# Hibernate Many-to-Many Relationship Not Loading Related Entities in Spring Boot 3.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I'm working on a Spring Boot (v `3.1.2`) application with Hibernate and facing an issue with a many-to-many relationship between Product and Discount entities. Here are my entity classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Product {
    // ... (fields and annotations)
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "products")
    private Set<Discount> discounts = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "discounts")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Discount {
    // ... (fields and annotations)
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "discounts_products",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "discount_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }
    )
    private Set<Product> products  = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have a repository for the Product entity with a basic findAll method:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
}
```

When I call productRepository.findAll(pageable), the discounts collection in the Product entities is always **empty**, even though I have matching data in my H2 database. Here's my application configuration:

```yaml
spring:
    config:
        activate:
            on-profile: dev
    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        password: ''
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
        username: sa
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
        show-sql: true
        defer-datasource-initialization: true
    sql:
        init:
            data-locations: classpath:sql/categories.sql, classpath:sql/products.sql, classpath:sql/discounts.sql
            mode: always
```

I've verified that the data in the database matches using the following SQL query:

```sql
select * from products p left join discounts_products dp on p.product_id = dp.product_id left join discounts d on d.discount_id=p.product_id;
```

What could be causing the discounts collection not to load, even though the data seems to be there in the database?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to quickly resolve the issue I was facing, even though it took me a few hours of debugging. The problem was related to the **@EqualsAndHashCode** annotation in my **Discount** entity. It turns out that this annotation was generating **equals()** and **hashCode()** methods that considered all fields, including the **products** field, which represents a many-to-many relationship with the Product entity. This led to circular references and potential infinite recursion.

To resolve the issue, I made adjustments to the @EqualsAndHashCode annotation as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "discounts")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Discount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer discountId;
    // Other fields and annotations...
}
```

we can also exlcude the `prodcuts`from generating `equals()` and `hashCode()`

```
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Product> products;
```

I hope this answer helps other who might encounter similar issue, if you have further explanation or alternative suggestion, please dont't hesitate to share. Your insights are highly valuable.